# WMI Access Denied

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I created a small application which has only one mission to make. It's to get remote computer's information. It works on release & debugs modes very fine. When I use it inside a ".net core" project the application gives "Access denied" error.

What I found so far.
If the cmd.exe run as SYSTEM, the application gives "Access denied" error, but in user mode, it works.

How can I use WMI in SYSTEM mode? What I do wrong?

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
{
   Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
   Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketIntegrity,
   EnablePrivileges = true,
   SecurePassword = the_secure_password_of_remote_computer,
   Username = the_username_of_remote_computer
};

var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + the_ip_address_of_remote_computer + 
                                        @"\root\cimv2", options);
try
{
   scope.Connect();
   if (scope.IsConnected)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      false;
   }
} catch(Exception exception)
{
   // I got the exception here.
   Console.WriteLine("Exception|{0}", exception.Message);
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Marshalling to solve this.

Here: http://rzander.azurewebsites.net/create-a-process-as-loggedon-user/

Comment: Can you add the code? This could be a good answer that can be upvoted, but right now it's not helpful for any future reader.